# Regarding file upload parameter in curl command

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm trying to run a curl command in azure devops bash script task, where I'm trying to upload a jar from artifact path.

I'm able to run it successfully while giving static file path in curl command, but how can we pass file path dynamically ?

```
curl -X POST \
https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/v2/applications \
-H 'authorization: bearer <your_token>' \
-H 'x-anypnt-env-id: <your_env_id>' \
-H 'x-anypnt-org-id: <your_org_id>' \
-F 'appInfoJson={
"domain": "<yourapplicationName>",
"muleVersion" : {"version":"3.9.1"},
"region" : "us-east-1", 
"monitoringEnabled":true,
"monitoringAutoRestart" : true,
"workers": {"amount":1, "type": {"name":"Micro","weight":"0.1","cpu":"0.1 vCores", "memory":"500 MB memory"}},
"loggingNgEnabled":true,
"persistentQueues":false,
 "properties":{
      "key1":"value1"
   }
}' \
-F autoStart=true \
-F file=@/path_to_the_file/yourapplication.jar
```

Is there any way to give the file path dynamically ? I tried to give this way   `-F file=@/path_to_the_file/**.jar` but `**` is not being accepted.

Comment: Can you set a variable with your filename and pass it to your curl?

Comment: I have tried that @Rakesh Gupta its not accepting

'variable =($ ls *.jar)
echo $variable

-F filepath=@"$variable"
'

Is the syntax Right ?

Comment: So, are you trying to attach multiple files?

Comment: no Im trying for single file but that file should be passed dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the filename in variable as shown below. Notice the {} around variable. Ensure that your ls command returns only 1 file. For multiple files use multiple -F arguments.

**Sample test data:**

```
$ ls *.jar
b.jar
$ echo $(ls -R ${PWD}/*.jar)
/root/b.jar
```

Above command generates absolute path to the file

```
-F file=@$(ls -R ${PWD}/*.jar)
```

${PWD} prints the path of the current working directory and helps to create the absolute path to the concerned file.

In addition, if you would like to attach multiple files, use multiple -F arguments

Comment: How can I pass the json object dynamically throught file .Can I use download secure file task in Azure devops and attach that file path in my script

Comment: Json object is passed with a diamond blade -d argument. Also ensure that the content-type header is set appropriately